# Modal vs Push - which is correct for my scenario?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have list of mail items in one View and I have nav bar button "New" to create new message.

All samples I've seen online say that this "new message" screen should be modal. We open it, write message and send it. Thats it. Since there is no navigation from this screen - it's use case typical modal view.

But I find that I really like "Push" this view. I get title for free, I get back button for free, I can add "Send" button to preconfigured title bar.

In code I can do "pop" on navigations stack after entered message processed. What's bad about it? So, it sounds like it should be modal but "push" much easier to do via storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Apple's Human Interface Guidelines:

> Use a modal view when you need to offer the ability to accomplish a
>   self-contained task related to your app’s primary function. A modal
>   view is especially appropriate for a multistep subtask that requires
>   UI elements that don’t belong in the main app UI all the time.

[Modal Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW3)

This is largely a preference thing and depends upon what you are trying to accomplish and whether you care if the user explicitly acknowledges his edits or not (i.e. save/cancel). It sounds like you have a reasonable case for push in your example so I would go with that. If you find that you are moving toward implementing features of a modal VC while using a push, then switch over to modal. I do not believe there is a hard and fast rule for this.

The following answer provides some additional nice reasons to go modal or push

[Modal vs. Push](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310557/3806828)